Why is my FRITZ!Repeater 1200 AX not being used?
Setup
I have a FRITZ!Box 7590 OG2, FRITZ!Repeater 1200 AX in OG1 east, FRITZ!WLAN Repeater 1750E in OG1 west and a FRITZ!Repeater 2400 in OG4 - due to building constraints I am limited to the one router in OG2. There are basically no cables here; Internet wasn't a thing when it was build.
My Issue
The 1200AX is new but for some reason nothing wants to connect to it. It is listed in my FRITZ!Box Mesh, but all devices connect to the 7590 instead even if the signal is significantly worse (Fritz Box wifi app). When I remove the 7590 from the equation, it even connects to the 2400 which has like -84 dBm compared to the -64 dBm the 1200 has. I do not understand where this is coming from, but usually I would expect some kind of optimization routine that decides which repeater to use intelligently.
Is it a problem that AX is mesh compatible and the other repeaters aren't in the Fritz Box sense? All share a single SSID as far as I can tell. Or is my AX1200 just broken in some way? Even when I walk far enough that the connection to the other repeaters breaks, I do not get a connection to the AX, but instead the connection breaks off completely. Turning wifi off and on on devices also doesn't make the AX more interesting for the devices.
I am currently considering sending the AX back because it doesn't seem to help with my issue (i.e. trying to get a better connection in the east).

Is your repeater perhaps using exotic Wi-Fi channels?

Or, another thought: Is it perhaps set to only accept 11ax devices?

how can I check whether it is using exotic Wi-Fi channels or whether it accepts only 11ax devices? I haven't knowingly changed any setting.

You can check which Wi-Fi channel is used by using a Wi-Fi scanner program/app. They will list networks, BSSIDs (important) and channels. You must look for the BSSID (often the MAC address) of your repeater. You should also be able to find the BSSID in the FritzBox web interface.
